# Redux Toolkit: Async Dispatch won't work in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make some async actions with redux toolkit in react-native. The project runs on redux without any issues, beside the implementation issues for createAsyncThunk.

I used the same logic as described in the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)

Within my Slice, I'm creating the createAsyncThunk Object as follows:

```
export const fetchAddressList = createAsyncThunk('/users/fetchAddresses', async(thunkAPI) => {
    const state = thunkAPI.getState();
    console.log("THUNK state.loggedIn: "+state.loggedIn);
    if(state.loggedIn){
        return apiHelper.getAddressDataAsync();
    }
});
```

It only differs in the export tag before const tag compared to the docs. I had to make it in order to access the fetchAddressList from outside. The apiHelper.getAddressDataAsync() is an async method, that returns the result of a fetch.

Than I added the **extraReducers** attribute to my slice object.

```
export const appDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "appDataReducer", 
  initialState:{
    //Some initial variables.
  },
  reducers: {
    //Reducers...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchAddressList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log("FULLFILLED::: ",action.payload);
        state.addressList = action.payload.addressList;
        state.defaultAddressId = action.payload.defaultAddressId;
    })
  }
});

export const { /*REDUCER_METHOD_NAMES*/ } = appDataSlice.actions;
```

This slice is stored in the store using configureStore, among other slices, that are definitely working fine.

Calling the fetchAddressList() method using dispatch doesn't do anything:

```
dispatch(fetchAddressList());
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Would appreciate any hints.

**Edit:**
Are there configurations required within the configureStore()-method when creating the store object?

This is how I create the store object:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      /*Other reducer objects....,*/
      appDataReducer: appDataSlice.reducer
    },
});
```

Maybe something is missing here...

Comment: So it does not console.log and also not crash?

Comment: @phry nope. No console.log appears and also no crash when calling the method. Would you mind to check my last edit? I added the part, where configureStore() is called. Maybe I'm missing some configuration there? Do I have to applyMiddleware()?

Comment: No need for any middleware - that one is already baked in. And if it were not present, I would also expect some kind of error/crash.
At this point I'm honestly pretty sure that that `dispatch` line is just never executed. Could you add a `console.log` before and after the `dispatch(fetchAddressList());` to test that?

Comment: @phry My code works after commenting out the thunkApi.getState() call! I did a console.log() before and after the dispatch(). These were both called / reached by the code. However the issue seems to happen at the `const state = thunkAPI.getState();` line. Doing a console.log before this line within the createAsyncThunk()-method is being executed, but the lines coming after the call to thunkAPI object are not. For some reason thunkAPI is undefined, but I would at least except an exception accessing undefined object then. Do you know by any chance why that object might be undefined?

Comment: @phry nvm. found the issue with thunkAPI. It has to be the second argument of the createAsyncThunk()-method. First parameter is reserved for the args to be passed in the dispatch(fetchByData(myArgs)) and the second one can either be thunkAPI itself or exports of it like getState or dispatch. See my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to wrong usage of the createAsyncThunk()-method. I'd passed the thunkAPI to be as the first (and only) parameter to the inner method, which was linked to user arguments passed through parameters into the initial dispatch method (like `dispatch(fetchAddressList("ARG_PASSED_TO_FIRST_PARAMETER_OF_ASNYCTHUNK"));`). However thunkAPI is being injected into the second parameter of createAsyncThunk()-method and as a result thunkAPI was `undefined`, since I hadn't passed any parameters by calling `dispatch(fetchAddressList());`

It was odd, to not have any errors / exceptions
calling a method of an undefined object though => `thunkAPI.getState()`.

The solution is to use the second parameter for thunkAPI.
You do have two options by doing so.

**1 - Either load the whole thunkAPI into the second parameter and use it as so:**

```
export const fetchAddressList = createAsyncThunk('/users/fetchAddresses', async(args, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log("TEST: ", thunkAPI.getState());
    thunkAPI.dispatch(...);
});
```

**2 - Or load exported methods by the thunkAPI:**

```
export const fetchAddressList = createAsyncThunk('/users/fetchAddresses', async(args,{getState, dispatch}) => {
    console.log("TEST: ", getState());
    dispatch(...);
});
```

Both ways will work. Happy coding :)